# Ever since I was a child 'I have been confronted' vs. 'I am confronted' - which is better: Present Perfect or Present Simple?

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> Ever since I was a child, I **have been** confronted with questions about my 'real' parents and my 'real' country.

and what if I say

Ever since I was a child, I **am** confronted with questions about my 'real' parents and my 'real' country.

Comment: [An answer to a related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6706/2127) (the question there is somewhat muddy, but the answer's fine).

Comment: One other good reference is Michael Swan's Practical English Usage, Unit 522. If I have time I'll write an answer based on it.

Comment: @CopperKettle While I was trying hard to search it, you mentioned the entry number! :)

Answer (score 3):

"I am" doesn't work because it refers to an action that happens now, where as "Ever since I was a child" refers to a whole period of time, most of which is in the past.  "I have been" refers to a continuous action over a period of time that began in the past and continues to the present, so that's what you want to use here.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the preferred choice is 'present perfect'.

*I am confronted...* will not serve the purpose here. **Because...**

if you want to say that you are confronted with those gruesome questions from ***one point of time till now***, you use *have been*.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ever) defines it:

> We use 'ever' before 'since' to emphasise that something has been true from the beginning of a specific period of time:

Why not the present?

It is occasionally used and used especially in sentences that talk about the ***'change'***.

Swan's PEU (Entry 522) says it:

> In sentences with *since* (referring to time), we normally use present perfect and past prefect tenses in the main clause.
>
> **However,** present and past tenses are also occasionally found, especially in sentences about *changes*

He further gives an example:

> *You **are** looking much better since your operation.*

Comment: But the same Dictionary gvies an example with Simple Present instead of Present Perfect: "Mrs Leech doesn’t go for walks on her own ever since she fell." It might be okay in colloquial speech.

Comment: @CopperKettle I read that example as well but somehow, to my ears, *have been* suits in this context. Maybe, I thought it in a general way - *I have been doing this thing since 1998* **over** *I am doing this...* The *continuity* there makes up the choice.

Comment: To me Past Perfect looks somewhat better too. [Here's an answer to a related question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6706/2127). The answerer there notes that in informal speech one meets such combinations, although Past Perfect is preferable.